# Paired data comparison: What statistical method to use?

Tags: panel-data, paired-data

I want to analyze the difference of two data collection rounds which took place in two different years with the same sample.
Companies were asked a few questions and afterwards the answers were analyzed into variables.

Now I want to compare these variables and outcomes, if they significantly differ.

What is the best statistical method to do this? I have paired data and an unbalanced panel ( in this two collection rounds, not each company answered all questions)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The test you should use will depend on the shape of the data distributions. You might consider parametric tests like t-tests, or non-parametric tests like Mann-Whitney U test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:

If you want to do a paired test of companies across the two different years (call them $i=1,2)$, you
must use *only* companies $j = 1,2, \dots, n$ that responded in both years. Then find differences
$d_j = Y_{1j} - Y_{2j}.$

If the sample of differences $d_j$ is approximately normally distributed
then you can do a one-sample t test on the differences for $H_0: \delta = 0$ against $\delta \ne 0,$ where $\delta$ is the mean change in the population
of participating companies between the two years.

If the sample of differences is clearly not from a normal population, but is nearly symmetrical, you might use a one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test
instead of a t test.

[Data below are fictitious data sampled using R for purposes of demonstration; of course, your real data may differ.]

For example, suppose differences are in vector `d` in R, with numerical
and graphical summaries as below:

```
summary(d);  length(d);  sd(d)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-58.010 -11.270  -3.747  -2.641   4.093  41.582 
[1] 100         # sample size
[1] 15.94684    # sample standard deviation
```

One hundred companies responded in both of the years. It seems that observations in the later year are larger (perhaps significantly larger), giving many negative differences.

```
boxplot(d, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

There are more boxplot ouliers in both tails than I would
anticipate from normal data, but the sample seems roughly
symmetrical.

Also a normal probability plot (quantile-quantile plot) of the
data is distinctly nonlinear.

```
qqnorm(d, datax=T);  qqline(d, datax=T, col="green3")
```

[image]

So, I choose the Wilcoxon SR test, which
rejects (5% level) the null hypothesis that the population is centered
at $0.$ The P-value is $0.032 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
wilcox.test(d)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 1901, p-value = 0.03205
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

---

*Note:* Fictitious data (Laplace distributed), used for illustration above, were sampled
in R as shown below:

```
set.seed(2021)
d = rexp(100, .1) - rexp(100, .1) - 1.5
```